# Hibernate removes "is" from fieldname

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For any reason hibernate (or the JpaRepository?) is removing the "is" part of my fieldnames in the rest api json document.

For example there is the field "is_active" in my Entity Class, on the json response the field is renamed to _active.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Why are you putting `_` in your field name? `isActive` is the Java naming convention.

Comment: Plus, that tiny detail of "JSON response" means it's Jackson, not Hibernate.

Comment: Thats right, but than the field is renamed to Active. "is" gets still filtered.

Comment: Json document? How does that relate to Hibernate or JPA? Why don't you show us the entity code and what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `@JsonProperty` directive:

```
@Test
void t() throws JsonProcessingException {
    C c = new C();
    String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(c);
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static class C {

    private boolean isActive = true;

    @JsonProperty("is_active")
    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.isActive = active;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "is_active" : true
}
```